# Keras layers.pop() is not removing layer

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

I am trying to remove the lambda layer at the end of my model but layers.pop() is not working for me:

```
conv1d_8 (Conv1D)            (None, None, 32)          2080      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, None, 128)         4224      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, None, 128)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, None, 1)           129       
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, None, 1)           0         
=================================================================
Total params: 19,009
Trainable params: 19,009
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The code above shows the last layers of the model. To remove the lambda layer I do the following:

```
model_old.layers.pop()
x = model_old.output
pred = Lambda(slice, arguments={'seq_length':7})(x)
new_model = Model(inputs=model_old.input, outputs=pred)
```

But for some reason when I print the summary the layer was not removed:

```
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, None, 1)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_5 (Lambda)            (None, None, 1)           0         
=================================================================
Total params: 19,009
Trainable params: 19,009
Non-trainable params: 0
```

How do you actually remove layers and add new ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by doing:

```
x = (model_old.layers[-2].output)
```